# Jquery ajax and server side method call error asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

i often use jquery to call my page method and it works fine. so now i am trying call page method from page1.aspx to page2.aspx. i am in page1.aspx and trying to call a page method which is in page2.aspx and here i am getting error.

this way i am calling page method-- jquery code and it is jquery short hand

```
function AjaxCallBack(MethodName, ObjParams, isAsync, OnSuccessHandler, OnErrorHandler) {
    try {
        //Set the callback methods for success and error
        if (OnSuccessHandler == undefined || typeof (OnSuccessHandler) == "undefined") {
            OnSuccessHandler = WebMethod_OnSuccess
        }

        if (OnErrorHandler == undefined || typeof (OnErrorHandler) == "undefined") {
            OnErrorHandler = WebMethod_OnError
        }
        //Serialize the webmethod function parameters
        var serializedParams = "";
        //using Json2.js; 
        serializedParams = JSON.stringify(ObjParams);
        alert(MethodName);
        //Make the ajax calls
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: isAsync,
            url: MethodName,
            data: serializedParams,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: OnSuccessHandler,
            error: OnErrorHandler
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(e.Message);
    }

    return;
}

AjaxCallBack(SetSessionUrl, SessionParam, false, UpdateSession, SessionUpdateError);
```

calling like above.

so please guide me what i need to change in my code as a matter i can call page2.aspx methos from page1.aspx file. please help me with code. thanks

Comment: What is the error message, that you did mention?

Comment: What contains `MethodName`? You normally only have to call `page2.aspx/<MethodOfPage2>`.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess how you use your code above as you didn't show any specific example. but did you also provide the path to the Page2.aspx rather just its method name??

Like

```
AjaxCallBack("page2.aspx/someWebMethod", ...)
```

Comment: sorry i did this but did not work...i think with the help of jquery we can not call cross page method.